# Planned maintenance scheduled for Thursday, June 15, 2023 at 21:00 UTC

Tags: discussion, announcements, maintenance

**tl;dr;** We are updating a piece of network hardware on [Thursday, June 15, 2023 at 21:00 UTC](https://time.is/compare/2100_15_June_2023_in_UTC), that will cause some internal traffic disruption for about a 1 minute duration. It's possible this could manifest some errors on the site while the network hardware restarts. The window for the update and restart is 1 hour from 21:00 UTC - 22:00 UTC.

### Short Version:

There's a bug in a piece of network hardware that caused the normal update process, which supports redundancy, to fail. This is forcing us to update and restart the unit that is actively handling traffic. We have performed this update process in our disaster recovery site and it was quick and uneventful. You can keep an eye on the maintenance via [our status page](https://www.stackstatus.net/).

### Longer Version of What's Taking Place:

I can't really think of a longer version. I'm not Tolkien after all. We just always have this section in our maintenance notification, so I figure I'll roll with it. Plus it helps the "short version" section make sense.

Comment: umm... status page clearly says it will be on June 16, 2023. So..... which day? Or will it be a surprise?

Comment: Clearly not using the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack, isn't status page using localtime? For me it shows 16th 12 a.m., so if my math is correct it would be 15th, 21:00 UTC

Comment: Doh! Yes, date was a typo. Have to remember to proofread the subject too.

Comment: Y'know what? Just leave the date out. Let us guess, it's more fun that way! :D (I'm kidding, thank you for communicating this with us, as always)

Comment: @markalex Yes the status page will show your local time.

Comment: Who is Tolkien?

Comment: @RandomPerson The author of *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings* books. He famously wrote long descriptive passages in the books.

Comment: @RandomPerson Are you sure your edit is good? The post also says "_The window for the update and restart is 1 hour from 21:00 UTC - 22:00 UTC._". Doesn't that mean the update could start at any time between 21:00 UTC - 21:59 UTC?

Comment: @starball Well, the date is not mentioned in the post and I added a link which one can use for seeing local time of the UTC time.

Comment: This guy i think:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._R._R._Tolkien @RandomPerson

Comment: What's the hardware and how did it break the update process?  Just curious.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I don't want to shoot the messenger or anything, but it would be nice if the various status pages we see during the outage could correctly link to an up-to-date version of this announcement where it can be viewed by us and updated by you as necessary. This has been a problem in the past, to the point where many users are skeptical of the various status pages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ had an internal server 500 error a few minutes ago, maybe its done?

Comment: The downtime we just experienced wasn't related to this maintenance. We'll be posting the details shortly.

Comment: See this post for more info on the recent outage: [Stack Exchange Network Outage – June 15, 2023](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390295/335251)

Comment: Is it over? All went as planned?

Comment: The maintenance is complete. Everything went as planned. If something else breaks... it wasn't me.

Answer (score 22):

The maintenance is complete. All systems operational. Thanks for playing "How to break your website in 7 easy steps."