# Let us go to the timeline of the post from homepage

Tags: feature-request, design, timeline

This is how the homepage looks like:

[image]

Beside the username, we have words like "asked", "answered", "modified", + date and time.

When the mouse pointer is over those words, we can notice that there's a hyperlink:

[image]

Example: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389558/stack-exchange-is-failing-its-community?lastactivity`

Instead of this link, it would be nice to have the timeline link of the post as users can easily access the timeline of the post from homepage and we can reduce the friction by decreasing the number of clicks.

---

Shadow Wizard raised a valid issue.  Let's say someone edited an answer of a post, the `?lastactivity` link will take us to the answer, instead of the question (I just realised this now). Maybe we can have 2 hyperlinks. One which will take us to the post where there was the last activity and the other link which will take us to the timeline.

Example:

| Current | Proposed |
| --- | --- |
| [modified Jun 14 at 5:19](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20332/we-may-need-to-migrate-away-from-the-stackexchange-platform-if-you-know-how-pl?lastactivity) | [modified](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20332/we-may-need-to-migrate-away-from-the-stackexchange-platform-if-you-know-how-pl?lastactivity) [Jun 14 at 5:19](https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/20335/timeline) |
| [modified 23 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390295/stack-exchange-network-outage-june-15-2023?lastactivity) | [modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390295/stack-exchange-network-outage-june-15-2023?lastactivity) [23 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/390306/timeline) |
| [modified yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389824/dear-se-please-stop-disparaging-the-moderators-in-the-press?lastactivity) | [modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389824/dear-se-please-stop-disparaging-the-moderators-in-the-press?lastactivity) [yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/390306/timeline) |

Update:

I added tooltips. This is how it would look:

[image]

Comment: -1 - - what happens when you want to view the post? Now you have *two* clicks to make. I agree with your concept, but I'd just say that SE could make the timeline link more obvious. Maybe a button at the top of the post instead of a link at the bottom?

Comment: @BentheCoder If you want to view the post from homepage, you can click on the question title. What do you mean by "*top of the post*"? The timeline link is near the votes button (the clock symbol). You're confusing timeline with revision history I guess.

Comment: I see. Still, I don't see much use in the timeline view. I only see use in the edit (or revision) history.

Comment: I'd would want to prioritize the edit history link, but I think the timeline button is good enough.

Comment: @BentheCoder We can see a bit of edit history through the timeline page. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI3OX.png)

Comment: I agree with @Ben, this would remove a very useful feature. If anything, add timeline link in addition to what we have now e.g below the score and number of views, but it will clutter the design so not sure if it's a good idea either.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack It would be more nice if we can access revision history using timeline. I will post another FR regarding that soon...

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack what do you mean remove a useful feature? I didn't get that part.

Comment: @RandomPerson I think ShadowW is referring to the ability to go right to the answer or modified question that is pointed to by the "answered 33 min ago" link.

Comment: @Conrado is correct, that's very useful feature I use many times, to see in one click what was modified. I don't want extra click for that, or having to see the timeline just for that.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack Came up with a solution :) I've edited the post, please check.

Comment: Still not ideal, very unclear one links to last activity and one to timeline. I'd go with [such design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFA9z.png), i.e. adding the timeline icon next to the modified timestamp in the list.

Comment: Maybe it would be more clear which link points where if instead of `?lastactivity` the links *both* pointed to, you know, the thing the link text said it was about. Then in the case of hidden revisions/answers, a redirect would match the eventual goal. And the case of clicking the link and getting somewhere completely unexpected would be gone.

Comment: @anx I'm sorry. I am unable understand what you mean.

Comment: @RandomPerson The link description is a lie. "[person] did [action] at [time]" refers to a *concrete action* - but `?lastactivity` more often than not leads me elsewhere. I keep using "old" (very active, actually) links and then cannot immediately tell whether the action I had wanted to review has been disappeared, or merely superseded. I think *neither* link should point to a *just give me whatever* URL, not with that link text anyway.

Comment: this sounds like a prime example of something that should just be a userscript

Comment: @KevinB haha... I wish I could make userscripts...

Comment: @anx I added tooltips. I hope that can help. Please check the edited question.

Comment: **Why?** This feature request describes the desired feature, _but not the use case that it satisfies_. What need is satisfied by being able to see the timeline for a post in the list view that is frequent enough to warrant making the UI that bit more complicated?

Answer (score 10):

##### Let's not do this

at least not on a permanent basis, i.e. not without explicitly enabling it in your profile. The timeline is an advanced feature, only power users (including me) are interested in it, and not even always. The homepage is already information-dense, adding more options only makes it more confusing to users, the vast majority of which only wants to read content.

Yes, a single icon won't hurt that much, but there are many other features out there which are just as useful, if we'd add them all it would become messy.

Comment: My approach wasn't really an icon, it was just a hyperlink and tooltips. But, I do understand your concern.

Comment: Oh, right, that was the top-voted answer, but I guess part of the same reasoning (especially *adding more options only makes it more confusing to users*) equally applies to having two links so close to each other.

Answer (score 7):

My userscript, [Post Ids Everywhere](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/PostIdsEverywhere.user.js), will display the post ID of all posts everywhere near each link/post for copying/searching. Double-clicking on it opens the post timeline.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think that this *concept* is good, but the way the OP has suggested implementing it isn't accepted by the community. I think that Shadow Wizard's idea (mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390349/let-us-go-to-the-timeline-of-the-post-from-homepage?noredirect=1#comment1303452_390349)) was probably the best. Shadow Wizard's also posted a screenshot of a very good plan to remedy this: put a timeline button beside the title link. This is what it might look like:

[image]